# How do I set a breakpoint within WlanSvc?

Tags: debug, svchost, windbg

My WiFi keeps getting disconnected, and I control my computer with Synergy. I've dug through the event logs and found that it all starts with a WlanSvcDisconnectRequest (part of the WlanSvc run under svchost.) I'm fairly confident that it's not a hardware fault.

I'm pretty sick and tired of having to replug my wifi dongle to get it to reconnect (for the computer is controlled with Synergy, and has no mouse/keyboard attached), so I decided to try to debug it to see if I could work out what's actually sending the WlanSvcDisconnectRequest every few minutes.

I tried my best to see if I could debug it, but can't seem to set the breakpoint.

I'm using the right version of WinDbg (64-bit) and running it as an elevated process.

I opened it, found the svchost process that's running the WlanSvc, and tried to set a breakpoint:

```
0:013> bc *
0:013> bp wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest
0:013> bl
 0 e 00007ff8`6d914ba8     0001 (0001)  0:**** wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest
0:013> g
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00007ff8`6d914ba8, Win32 error 0n998
    "Invalid access to memory location."
The breakpoint was set with BP.  If you want breakpoints
to track module load/unload state you must use BU.
bp0 at 00007ff8`6d914ba8 failed
WaitForEvent failed
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1:
00007ff8`75729921 c3              ret
```

I also tried setting it as an unresolved breakpoint:

```
0:013> bc *
0:013> x wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest
00007ff8`6d914ba8 wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest = <no type information>
0:013> bu wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest
0:013> g
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00007ff8`6d914ba8, Win32 error 0n998
    "Invalid access to memory location."
bp0 at 00007ff8`6d914ba8 failed
WaitForEvent failed
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint+0x1:
00007ff8`75729921 c3              ret
```

I haven't used WinDbg before, but a large amount of Googling was done to no avail. Why am I unable to set the breakpoint for `wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest`?

---

WinDbg version:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 AMD64
```

System info:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~1867 Mhz
```

Symbol path:

```
srv*;C:\Symbols\wlansvc.pdb
```

---

Update: Tried disabling ASLR with EMETS, did not help with trying to set the breakpoint.

Comment: Have you tried another wifi dongle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest` is actually a data structure stored in `.rdata` section of `wlansvc.dll`. It is stored in read-only memory and doesn't contain any code. Thus creating a breakpoint doesn't make any sense.

You can verify it by `!address wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest` command. It will report `PAGE_READONLY` page protection for given memory region.

If you want to break when some code accesses that structure, you will need to set a *data breakpoint*:
`ba r1 wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest`

Or you may just put standard brakpoint to `wlansvc!IntfDisconnect` function as this seems to be the only one place that contains reference to `wlansvc!WlanSvcDisconnectRequest` structure (that could be found using [IDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Disassembler) disassembler for example).

Comment: Thank you! I really do appreciate it. I'll give that a shot this afternoon.